# i tried to submit the form and extract the inside text but not getting the expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am trying to extract doctors information by sumbitting pincode in corresponding address pincode in the form but fail to get.

i have tried to extract , but getting some other text using data in network tab.
below is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'http://www.delhimedicalcouncil.org/app/search_ur_dr.php'
data = {
    'Corr_Add_Pincode': '110053',
    'g-recaptcha-response': '03AOLTBLSHMG-kZO4nOEd4LkmCwYgA-8HuCalKjhjYOASByz7z2Z53lU6n1CdwwgHUUbc6ma6WJNyTMTlNIT-JAbMjO2V5QwDC1MeZCU8y7HchqNgG4HRDCY6MRSWC1A9QikPWEolzexeDE42QsuY73h8yEWG2fBzMzkEKt8hdrI0V3UjYRtHT7DluGeCzmBfUCEKT_O5Aquiqh9j9gZds3xD1rJJhzli239ItWHErt8DXWXUaxQEpfSr2sIrZfOMw486_-OLpjr99A9Q3r830QV2VAnqgB8yO7Xz81FO-eP8KAUVIhBBs0DG55dyEmqIuBYknRQ3sQxFbJgkCYAnhjSeZuQV4YIDWrNMCbX7vTHFFSfqSMrQ-DjwM-rHlcJ5j3egt3ve6_X3vbwA6nJsjHZvNYKUlapRO6Q',
    'submit': 'Search'
    }

r = requests.get(link,data=data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

div = soup.find('div',class_='intro')
tables = div.find_all('table')
for table in tables[0:1]:
    print(table.text)
```

want doctors informations by submiting pincode , but getting some other text.
help me someone to crack this problem.

Comment: I guess it should be `requests.post` instead of `requests.get`.

Comment: I tried but its not working @Sukumar Rdjf

Comment: The website is using recaptcha to stop automated scripts. Your response is almost certainly going to be wrong.

Comment: ok. so can you help me to crack this @MartinEvans